Can't install sourcery version 2.0.2
I have installed swiftymocky using following commands:
brew tap spaluchiewicz/homebrew-swiftymocky
brew install swiftymocky.

And installed sourcery using following commands:
mint install sourcery@2.0.2. So i am getting error   "sourcery" package not found.

While running the swiftymocky doctor getting:

⚠️  Mint does not yet have matching Sourcery version installed.

and can't generate the mocky file. How to install compatible sourcery version to gerenate the mocky file?
And while running  swiftymocky generate I am getting

Status code: 1
Message: "  "sourcery" package not found"

How to install sourcery 2.0.2 version via mint?

Executing following command in terminal worked:
1)git config --global tag.forcesignannotated false
2)open ~/.gitconfig in terminal then remove: [safe] bareRepository = explicit save it and that's it
Source tree adds above line to the files
After this you can install swiftymocky and sourcery through mint and everything works as expected.
Also above commands help when SPM fails to resolve the package graph
